# The component of $T − e$ containing $v$ has at least as many vertices as the component not containing $v$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> $\textbf{Claim:}$ For every tree $T$ there exists a vertex $v$ such that for every edge $e$ the component of $T − e$ containing $v$ has at least as many vertices as the component not containing $v$.

I am trying to prove it by contradiction, but not able to see what property of tree to contradict!

$\textbf{Observations:}$

1) The vertex $v$ can't be a leaf vertex for a tree of large size.

2) $T - e$ has two components always.

3) We can always find a vertex $v$ in the tree such that the number of vertices on the left side of $v$ is almost same as the number of vertices on the right side. They atmost  differ by $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Every tree has a *centroid* of one vertex or two adjacent vertices. A vertex is part of the centroid if it minimises the maximum order of the components formed by removing said vertex from the tree. A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2476346/357390).

Let $T$ have $n$ vertices and $v$ be any vertex in the centroid. Removing $v$ creates components with order at most $n/2$. Any edge $e$ lies in one of these components or links one of them to $v$, so the order of the component not containing $v$ in $T-e$ must be at most $n/2$. Hence the order of the component with $v$ is at least $n/2$, and the claim follows.